# Problems adding mimetype.assign to lighttpd.conf

Tags: lighttpd

I tried to add mimetype.assign = ( ".webapp" => "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" ) to my lighty conf file but got an error when restarting.

First the conf file:

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_redirect",
#       "mod_rewrite",
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www/servers/www.nope.dyndns.org/pages/"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80

mimetype.assign   = ( ".webapp" => "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" )

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"
```

...and the error:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lighttpd restart
Duplicate config variable in conditional 0 global: mimetype.assign
2014-01-03 21:12:55: (configfile.c.943) source: /usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl line: 500 pos: 1 parser failed somehow near here: (EOL) 
2014-01-03 21:12:55: (configfile.c.943) source: /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf line: 29 pos: 14 parser failed somehow near here: (EOL)
```

I took a guess and added the missing "application/x-web-app-manifest+json webapp" to the long list of mime-types in /etc/mime.types, but this didn't fix the problem.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If you have `include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
` you can't also have `mimetype.assign = ` because it creates it. I think you're on the right course modifying `/etc/mime.type`. Maybe you have a syntax error, you can run the script as `perl /usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl` to see its output or if it executes with errors.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I ran perl /usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl, and it came back peachy.

So I guess if I remove that line, I just create all the mime-types I want to serve myself?

Comment: Oh wait, I just realised, so by adding  "application/x-web-app-manifest+json webapp" to /etc/mime.types, I should be able to serve .webapp content. And no need for adding the extra like you said. I guess the error makes more sense now.

Answer (score 9):

I hope You found out by now, but, for the sake of whoever is googling around...

Right syntax to add a value to an array is:

```
mimetype.assign   += ( ".webapp" => "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" )
```

Notice the "+="; that merges the new value(s) into the existing array.

Comment: Thank you! This changed at some point and I could not figure out why my old lighttpd configuration was blowing up.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment by ZioByte, you might also consider using the `:=` operator to update the `mimetype.assign` array.

```
mimetype.assign   := ( ".webapp" => "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" )
```

This will overwrite any existing keys in `mimetype.assign`, whereas `+=` throws an error.

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_configuration